# Async sockets and AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, events

I have an application where the main app creates a loop and waits for a method return some data.
i.e

```
Main.cs
var obj = new MySuperClass();
MyData data; 
while (obj.ReadData(out data)) {
  // do something with data
}
```

The data itself comes from an Async socket connection, thus I'm using an AutoResetEvent to signal when data is ready so the main app can consume it.

```
class MySuperClass {
  private MyData _dataFromSocket;
  private AutoResetEvent _ev = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  public bool ReadData(out MyData data) {
    _autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    data = _dataFromSocket;
    // here more logic to return false, but that's not the case or the issue
    return true;  

  }

  /// async socket callback and data parse
  private void MyAsyncCallback(byte rawData) {
    while (canParse(rawData, out _dataFromSocket)) { // somehow parse the raw bytes 
      //if we could parse, signal that we have a packet
      _ev.Set(); // set the signal
    }
  }
}
```

When the `_ev` is set, the `Read` returns, the main app gets the data and everybody is happy. 
But in some cases, when `AsyncCallback` is called with a large buffer where I can deserialize multiple packets, i.e. 5, the main app will receive only 2 or 3, is like the event Skips reseting and `Read` method doesn't return immediately.

Any idea how to fix this? Is there a faster Event implementation that would signal faster.

I cannot change the architecture of the app, these were the requirements, it must work in the main thread, how data comes it doesn't care, and in this case, I must use async sockets.

Thx for any ideas.

Comment: What does parseData do?

Comment: do you mean `canParse`? Just tries to convert raw bytes into a type structure

Comment: You haven't posted all the code so I'm taking a good guess. Sockets are using TCP protocol where there are four conditions that can happen 1) Messages are broken up into datagrams of max size of 1500 bytes 2) The datagrams can be broken and combined as they are transmitted from source to destination 3) Datagrams with zero bytes can be transmitted which are keep-alive messages 4) So when the Async Callback gets a message it must be able to handle fragmented messages.  The solution is to add a terminator to each message either by preceding data with byte count or add a terminator like a return.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a synchronized queue (FIFO). You assign in your `MyAsyncCallback` the result to a global variable and read it in `ReadData` any time in the future without any synchronization. That's suboptimal and cannot work.

Simplified improvement:

```
class MySuperClass
{
  private readonly object _syncRoot  = new object();
  private Queue<MyData>   _dataQueue = new Queue<MyData>();
  private AutoResetEvent  _ev        = new AutoResetEvent(false);

  public bool ReadData(out List<MyData> dataList)
  {
    dataList = new List<MyData>();

    _autoResetEvent.WaitOne();

    lock(_syncRoot) // lock access to queue for other threads
    {
      while(_dataQueue.Count > 0)
      {
        dataList.Add(_dataQueue.Dequeue());
      }
    }        

    return true;  
  }

  /// async socket callback and data parse
  private void MyAsyncCallback(byte rawData)
  {
    MyData data;

    while (canParse(rawData, out data)) 
    { // somehow parse the raw bytes 
      //if we could parse, signal that we have a packet

      lock(_syncRoot) // lock access to queue for other threads
      {
        _dataQueue.Enqueue(data);
      }
    }
    _ev.Set(); // set the signal after all packets parsed, depends on your requirements, maybe after each?
  }
}
```

Comment: thx KBO, I had a similar assumption about using a queue but wanted to get a second opinion. I'll see if someone else has some other ideas.

Comment: It's better to use `BlockingCollection` with `ConcurrentQueue` inside. Then you can remove all locks and `AutoResetEvent` too.

Comment: @Evk: Ok, there are many ways, depending on the real implementation. I wanted to demonstrate the (simple) usage only. If you wait for incoming packets, you may also use a background thread. If so, you can use the event to wake it up on new packets and let it sleep the remaining time. In combination with a `CancellationToken` that works well.